# Hide Template Name

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

Is it possible to hide the name of a Joomla 3 template, e.g while looking at 'view source' in a browser?

I know it's possible to rename the temate but this doesn't hide the name, it's still visible in all the css/js paths etc

I assume there are a lot of template related urls that would need changed or hidden? Not sure if anything can be changed in the .htaccess or not?

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, sort of... but you have to be careful.  Take this scenario:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^css/(.*) /templates/purity_iii/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*) /templates/purity_iii/js/$1 [L]
```

This would work fine, as long as you don't have any css or js outside of your theme path, for example:

```
/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js
/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js
/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js
/media/system/js/caption.js
```

So in short, it depends on the template you're using, and your skill with htaccess.

Comment: `as long as you don't have any css or js outside of your theme path` >> So seeing as Joomla 3.x by default imports JS files from the above directory, will your `RewriteRule` work?

Comment: No, those would remain as is.  If you wanted to remove that as well it would mean stopping the bootstrap auto loader, and manually adding each of the JS files.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you can do that I know of is rename the template folder of the template you're using. This may seem like it makes no difference but sometimes it can, especially if you're using a one from a popular template provider where the prefix is well known.

If you do change your template folder name, make sure you reactivate it in the Template Manager so the new name is taken into account

Answer (score 1):

It is actually easy (just discovered)
In admin go to extensions and click templates, then on the left click templates
Click the link to your template
It will show you the structure and files on the left, at the top click copy template
Give it a new name

Thats it, now you have a copy of the template in your own name

Comment: Congrats on responding to a two year old question...