# Rename my template

Tags: joomla-3.x, template-override

I'm trying to to change the name of the default `Protostar` template so that **/templates/protostar/** is not visible in my source code.

I tried by creating a new style with a new name in the template manager, but nothing was changed in the source code. How can I rename my template?

Comment: This question was already asked less than a week ago [here](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5429/hide-template-name). Please do some research before asking questions as it will most likely have already been answered.